# Como faço pra colocar a propriedade usermanager ser iniciado na minha Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Queria que no formulário o campo **Nome** seja preenchido automaticamente pelo nome do usuário que esta logado.

Como incluir essa propriedade na minha **Model**?

```
     public class Condominio
     {


         public int CondominioId { get; set; }


         public string Nome { get; set; }

         public int CEP { get; set; }

         public string Endereco { get; set; }


         public int Numero { get; set; }  
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Em *Controller*:

```
var condominio = new Condominio { Nome = User.Identity.Name };
return View(condominio);
```

Comment: Adicionei na action Create/GET e funcionou perfeitamente. Grato

Comment: @ElóiFerreira [Veja como o site funciona aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string Nome{
  get{
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"] != null)
             return  HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"];
   }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.